# Posting JSON file with WebClient?

Tags: c#, json

Trying to post json to a url with WebClient:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
     client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     client.UploadFile("https://coolWebsite.com/ext/ext/ext", @"C:\Users\ME\coolJson.json");

}
```

My post still isn't being recognized as json, however. What's wrong with the way I try to add Headers here and how do I customize this post so the url interprets my file as json?

EDIT: I am printing the ResponseHeaders and they are null - could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Your two lines of code seems OK, Read the docs of your site to find what else it needs.

Comment: What does the server response with?

Comment: @Nathan_A It is a custom response indicating that the file I'm uploading is "empty". I've experienced the same problem in Powershell, and fixed it by adding the "content-type", "application/json" tag somewhere in the code. The server thinks (I think) I am trying to literally post the file path as a string.

Comment: Are you trying to post JSON data or upload a JSON file?  Two different things.

Comment: I am trying to upload a JSON file.

Comment: Are you sure the server is not expecting form data? Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I have the exact same POST method running, successfully, in Powershell: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://coolWebsite.com/ext/ext -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Body $someJsonFile`

Comment: Can anyone recommend debugging techniques? I.e. a way to display, as @L.B suggested, something along the lines of: `Error - Expected[type - x], Received[type - y]`? A way to print what the server needs vs. what I am providing?

Comment: You say you got it working in Powershell? Then use Fiddler or Wireshark to watch the network traffic and see how your Powershell vs your C# attempts differ.

Comment: In your working PowerShell code, what is in the `$someJsonFile` variable?  Is it a file name, or the actual JSON?